# Don't connect to mysql server when accessing static pages

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't want my rails app to connect to mysql server when I access static pages. For a real example which I'm encountering: 
When mysql server machine dies, all my apps also die include both static pages (pages have no mysql query) and dynamic pages.

My Expectation is when mysql server dies, only dynamic pages die but  static pages remain. I want to still have access to static pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik You can't.  However what you can do is have a display static pages directly from the underlying apache or nginx server, when the main app is down

If you are on apache follow this guide:

https://viget.com/extend/server-maintenance-mode-for-rails-capistrano-and-apache2

Basically you will have a file the presence of which turns on your maintenance mode pages.

You still have to turn on the maintenance mode manually, although this could be automated as well.

Comment: Thanks @Mich VanDuyn. Can you tell detail more ? why not do that and how do with apache or nginx server.

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx